# Is there a good way to display (big) numbers in different bases?

Tags: best-practice, numbers

Big numbers in base 10 are displayed with a dot every 3 digits*, like:

```
1.000.000.000.000.000
```

Base 2 numbers are different, probably is better to have no divisions:

```
0000001010001011111101
```

But what about different bases "big" numbers? Is there some rule, best practice, or advice to display big numbers?

```
234341111432104313222312131304423113044233031031 (which is 1.982.983.918.239.829.381.293.892.381.923.891 in base 5)

24d808941c097c3aa64d9a98d58e6 (same number in base 15)
```

Do you have any advice?

*(ok, this is not always true, but I'm developing a dashboard where big numbers has the dot as separator, but should be the comma ",")

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be a better question for the people at [mathoverflow.se]. I'd imagine that if there is a convention, they'd know better than us.

Comment: good point, maybe I'll post there the question if I can't find anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer here. Modern C++ uses a single quotation mark as a separator.

Not that long numbers in any base are readable. They are just strings of characters to a human. If you insist on displaying the number as a whole then I'd suggest using a fixed width font. Then the user can just compare the length and look for the first differing digit when comparing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

How is it useful to display this information? What is the context, can you give us a little bit more information?

Use abbreviation for large numbers: [Names of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers)

If you want to display a string of code, depending on the users need, you can:

a) Truncate the string

b) Truncate the string and show it on rollover (progressive disclosure)

Comment: The main context is that users should be able to se "bigger" numbers at a glance, and read them if needed, something like "11.000.000.000" is bigger than "1.000.000" but this could happen also in different bases